# C# exe - multiple users sharing one instance of exe file

Tags: c#, exe, remote-desktop, windows-process

I am experiencing some issues with running exe file by multiple users. We have 10 users, all connecting via remote desktop to the same computer (server) under different user accounts.

When user opens document in Document management application and clicks edit, exe is called, which opens the document in Word. The issue is that this works perfectly for first user only (the user who started the exe app). When User A clicks edit and starts the app, document is opened as a process under his account. When User B clicks edit (exe is already running), the document process is opened under User A account - hence, Word document opens for User A - which makes sense, since exe is running under the user who started the application, and exe is holding the process of invoking user.

Has anyone dealt with similar issues? What would be the best approach to resolve this issue - each user should get his own thread or process from which exe logic would execute.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, spawning a new process on Windows **always** spawns a **new** process, it does not simply reuse an existing process. However, that process may then forward the request to open something to the other "main" process, could be that however this is implemented does not take into account user contexts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.